# Predefining an array of tuples

Tags: multiprocessing, julia

I am attempting to populate an array of tuples in a for-loop. The array needs to be predefined.

I am trying to do something along the following lines:

```
for class in keys(classes)
    arr[class]=pmap(y->func(arg,y),1:length(arg1),batch_size=Int(round(length(arg)/nworkers())))
end
```

In the specific case, `classes` is a dictionary of type `Dict{String,Tuple{Int64,Int64}}`. For e.g. `classes=Dict("Item1" => (5000,10000), "Item2" => (5000,10000))`

The type-definition of broadcasting operation `pmap(...)` when `class` is `Item1` is an `Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,1}},1}`. What is an appropriate way of preallocating `arr`?

`arr[Item1]` will be of type `Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,1}},1}`. So, I presume `arr` would have to defined as an `Array{Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,1}},1}}`, or something to this extent. But, I couldn't come up with the right notation for defining this.

Comment: What would improve the question is to have code that defines a simple example of `classes` and what else is needs to be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I have overthought this; defining `arr` as a `Dict{String,Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64,Float64,Array{Float64,1}},1}}` was helpful.